Golang cosmosdb-gremlin connection
Anyone has golang sample to connect to cosmosdb-gremlin over wss, preferably using Primary key or connection string? So far I have tried gremlingo, gramess etc but nothing resulted in successful connection. Thanks on advance for any pointers.
So far I have tried gremlingo, gramess etc but nothing resulted in successful connection.
Below is the code I tried for example:
func createGremlinClient() *gremlingo.DriverRemoteConnection{
    endpoint := "wss://<url-here>.cosmos.azure.com:443/" 
    accessKey := "my-primarykey-here"

    client, err := gremlingo.NewDriverRemoteConnection(endpoint,
        func(settings *gremlingo.DriverRemoteConnectionSettings) {
        settings.TraversalSource = "g"
        settings.NewConnectionThreshold = 4
        settings.EnableCompression = false
        settings.ReadBufferSize = 0
        settings.WriteBufferSize = 0
        settings.AuthInfo = &gremlingo.AuthInfo{
            Header:   http.Header{"Authorization": []string{accessKey}},
            Username: "",
            Password: accessKey,
        }
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil
    }
    return client
}

below is the error I am getting:
2024/04/18 16:16:34 Failed to instantiate the new connection; setting connection state to closed.
2024/04/18 16:16:34 Error creating new connection for connection pool: websocket: bad handshake
2024/04/18 16:16:34 Error occurred during operation NewDriverRemoteConnection: 'E0104: no successful connections could be made: websocket: bad handshake'
After passing connection string instead of endpoint URL, I still get same error.
Update:
I modified the code like below and gives different error:
package main

import (

    "crypto/tls"

    "fmt"

    gremlin "github.com/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin-go/v3/driver"

    "net/http"

    "time"

)

func createGremlinClient() *gremlin.DriverRemoteConnection {

    endpoint := "<endpoint>"

    accessKey := "<primary-key>"

    client, err := gremlin.NewDriverRemoteConnection(endpoint, func(settings *gremlin.DriverRemoteConnectionSettings) {

        settings.ConnectionTimeout = 45 * time.Second

        settings.ReadBufferSize = 4096

        settings.WriteBufferSize = 4096

        settings.TlsConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}

        settings.AuthInfo = &gremlin.AuthInfo{

            Header:   http.Header{"Authorization": []string{accessKey}},

            Username: "/dbs/g",

            Password: accessKey,

        }

    })

    if err != nil {

        fmt.Println("Error creating Gremlin client:", err)

        return nil

    }

    return client

}

func main() {

    client := createGremlinClient()

    if client == nil {

        fmt.Println("Gremlin client creation failed.")

        return

    }

    g := gremlin.Traversal_().WithRemote(client)

    query := g.AddV().Iterate()

    count, _ := g.V().Count().Next()

    err := <-query

    if err != nil {

        fmt.Println(err)

        return

    }

    fmt.Println("Vertex count:", *count)

    defer client.Close()

}

Error I get is:
2024/04/19 10:52:19 Connecting.
2024/04/19 10:52:19 Read loop error 'websocket: close 1011 (internal server error): Internal-Server-Error', closing read loop.
2024/04/19 10:52:19 Read loop error 'websocket: close 1011 (internal server error): Internal-Server-Error', closing read loop.
2024/04/19 10:52:19 Connection error callback invoked, closing protocol.
websocket: close 1011 (internal server error): Internal-Server-Error
I think for Cosmos-Gremlin GraphDB the collection/containers dont apply, do the username I am passing may not make sense, I tried passing an empty string as well with no luck.

Could you share what you tried and also the error you are facing with?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

gremlin-go doesnt seem to be compatible with Azure Cosmos db, I tried another driver named gremco and it worked.


Golang cosmosdb-gremlin connection

As this document suggests Cosmos DB Gremlin connection with Python, Node.Js and .NET languages. The possible dependencies are available with these languages to connect with Cosmos DB Gremlin API. So, It is throwing error while trying to connect with GO.
Below is the .NET code which connects successfully with Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin API.
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string hostname = "<account_name>.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com";
    int port = 443;
    string primaryKey = "*****";
    string database = "newdb";
    string collection = "newgraph";

    var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer(
        hostname,
        port,
        true,
        $"/dbs/{database}/colls/{collection}",
        primaryKey
    );

    var gremlinClient = new GremlinClient(
        gremlinServer,
        new GraphSON2Reader(),
        new GraphSON2Writer(),
        mimeType: "application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json" 
    );

    string gremlinQuery = "g.V()";

    var results = await gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<Dictionary<string, object>>(gremlinQuery);

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Vertex ID: {result["id"]}, Label: {result["label"]}");

        var properties = result["properties"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
        if (properties != null)
        {
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var propertyName = property.Key;
                var propertyValue = property.Value;

                if (propertyValue is Dictionary<string, object> innerDict)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Property Name: {propertyName}, Value (Dictionary):");

                    foreach (var kvp in innerDict)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Inner Key: {kvp.Key}, Inner Value: {kvp.Value}");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Property Name: {propertyName}, Value: {propertyValue}");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No properties found for this vertex.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(); 
    }
}

Output:
Vertex ID: 22946583-c99d-4b37-8e02-808d1287346e, Label: Name
Property Name: name, 
Value: System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Text.Json.JsonElement,System.Object]


looking for go sample, I do have working .net and Java code
